# Global handling of 401 Responses with RestKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I am currently working on an iOS App that is developed using Swift.  For the REST calls, I am using the RestKit framework.

The next stage of my project is to start using authentication against the services.  An issue that I have come up against is handling 401 (Not Authenticated) responses from the service.  In all of these circumstances, I would like to display a login page.  I want to avoid implementing the error handling of this multiple times.

I followed the tutorial at http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2013/09/03/global-request-management-with-restkit/.  However, this is in Objective-C and I would like to do things slightly differently.

As such, I want to build a class that extends RKObjectRequestOperation as in the tutorial but using Swift.  I have come up with an issue as I am receiving the error

> Overriding method with selector 'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:' has incompatible type '((RKObjectRequestOperation, RKMappingResult) -> Void (RKObjectRequestOperation, NSError) -> Void) -> Void'

I am a bit stuck on this and so was hoping someone could help.  The code for the method that is failing is below.

```
class CustomRequestOperation : RKObjectRequestOperation {
    func setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(success: (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation, mappingResult: RKMappingResult) -> Void, failure: (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation, error: NSError) -> Void) -> Void {

    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my method signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the method so you can get Xcode to add the signature for you if you start typing the method name and hie escape.

It should be

```
func setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(success: (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation, mappingResult: RKMappingResult) -> Void, failure: (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation, error: NSError) -> Void) {
```

(you are adding a return spec that doesn't exist in the superclass method)

Comment: Thanks!  This didn't quite work but your comment about Xcode autocompleting worked.  The correct method was: `override func setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(success: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, RKMappingResult!) -> Void)!, failure: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {`

Comment: Do you have the rest of the implementation in swift from that article?  I'm having trouble getting the rest of the code converted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full class in swift...

```
class CustomRKObjectRequestOperation : RKObjectRequestOperation
{

    override func setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(success: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, RKMappingResult!) -> Void)!, failure: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {


        super.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation, RKMappingResult mappingResult) -> Void in

            if ((success) != nil) {
                success(operation, mappingResult);
            }

            }, failure: { (RKObjectRequestOperation operation, NSError error) -> Void in

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("connectionFailure",object:operation)

                if ((failure) != nil) {
                    failure(operation, error);
                }

        })

    }
}
```

App Delegate

Register notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"connectionFailedWithOperation:",name:"connectionFailure", object:nil) 

func connectionFailedWithOperation(notification: NSNotification  ){


    let operation = notification.object as! RKObjectRequestOperation?;
    if ((operation) != nil) {

        let statusCode = operation!.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode;

        if (statusCode == 401) {

            // log user out


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now in swift 3.0  override func setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(success: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, RKMappingResult!) -> Void)!, failure: ((RKObjectRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!)  is throwing an error  "Method does not override any method from its superclass"